# Multiple independent Views attachment pagers (load more)

Tags: views

I have a view with two attachments. I want to have a **load more** button to load items for each attachment and the main view separately, I have the [**load more**](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more) module, but it loads more items for all the views, not for each attachment separately. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have unique pager id's for all your view displays.
You will find the option in Views under the paging section of your display.

**EDIT**

As noted below, attachments don't have the option to add a unique ID, this is a known limitation. See for example this discussion on [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/1082334).

It is currently not possible to solve this issue in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) only. If you want different paging options, you can not use attachments. A workaround is to use block displays and place them on the same page as the main view. (Do change the pager ID of the block views only if there are still problems).

Comment: The pager settings in the attachment does not have ID.

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. This is one way you can solve the issue by doing it, But what about if i have common exposed filters? how can it be applied to all blocks?